# OL3 3.5 Projection Issue

Tags: postgis, openlayers-3

I am getting GeoJson from Postgres.

When I transform to 3857 (from 4326) in postgres I get this for an extent:
[-1150534050240.958, NaN, -1150492727057.5322, NaN]

When I remove transformation from postgres and let OL3 do the transform I get this:
[-10335423.222313922, 3843466.0274247285, -10335052.00984128, 3843760.3957394864]

In 3.0 and older we always transformed in postgres before serving to OL3.

Is there an issue with 3.5 getting already transformed geojson? Anyone know of known issues with postgres/postgis and OL3 3.5?

Thank You!

*** snippet
    vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: new ol.source.Vector({
            format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
            url:'myProxy'
        }),

p.s. from:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ol3-dev/R4zdhY3qex8

Comment: So it looks like that everything is right with ol3.

Comment: No, the extent returned has nan when I project in Postgres. And does not display line string. As soon as I leave 4326 and let client / ol3 transform it works fine. I would like to transform on server rather than client. Thank you!

Comment: when this happens to me on ol3, it's because the value is parsing as string and not as a float number.

Comment: Perhaps you could post the actual coordinates you are transforming as WKT or similar?

Comment: I agree with john post the ST_astext and the code for the extent transformation. For what i see the problem is Postgres transformation not OL because that NaN. Just yesterday I make my postgres tranform several linestring from 4326 to 3857. Create a webservice to pass OL and work very good.